# How can i preload all components and routes in Svelte?

Tags: node.js, svelte

I have a game project based on Svelte. When the homepage opens, I want other pages to load the files as well. For example, when you go to the lobby creation page from the home page, the images are loaded from scratch.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add [preload link elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload) to the `<head>` to preload files, they look like this:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" />
<link rel="preload" href="script.js" as="script" />
```

Valid `as` values can be found e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-as).

(Should be possible to those via [`<svelte:head>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-head) as well, but I never tried that.)